# How do I validate a date string format in python?

Tags: python, date

I have a python method which accepts **a date input as a string**.

How do I add a validation to make sure the date string being passed to the method is in the ffg. format:

```
'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

if it's not, method should raise some sort of error

Comment: It might be more Pythonic (ask for forgiveness, not permission) not to check at all, and catch any resulting exceptions that occur.

Comment: Related: [In python, how to check if a date is valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9987818/55075)

Answer (score 345, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> def validate(date_text):
        try:
            datetime.date.fromisoformat(date_text)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")

    
>>> validate('2003-12-23')
>>> validate('2003-12-32')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    validate('2003-12-32')
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 5, in validate
    raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
ValueError: Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD
```

Note that `datetime.date.fromisoformat()` obviously works only when date is in ISO format. If you need to check date in some other format, use `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.

Comment: Is there a way of doing that without a try/except? Python tends to slow down significantly when an exception is raised and caught.

Comment: @chiffa You could match a date format regex but its not recommended because it's less robust and exceptions are clearer. Are you sure date validation is your bottleneck?

Comment: Not really, so in the end I will just wrap throw-except construct in a function. I am just surprised that there is no bool-returning validating function that would trigger the Exception throw in the datetime library.

Comment: @chiffa Maybe they didnt include bool returning validating function on purpose, it might exist in external libraries

Comment: I know its been over a year, but I was parsing some logs, and happen to be stripping out lines that did not start with a date.  I just tested the suggested method against checking the timestring for "startswith(<current year>)".  ~590k lines of logs. Using dateutil parser and its exceptions : 129 sec.  Using dumb as hell "startswith": 3 sec.  Now I know it doesn't work for everyone, but if a method that works in most cases is 2 orders of magnitude faster, its 2 orders of magnitude faster.  I got about 2000x more logs to work through for my script, guess what I'm gonna use?

Comment: For those who want zero padding in dates, this solution won't work as strptime is not strict about zero padding. Implement a regex of your own or check the length of the resultant string after stripping whitespace and then make use of this solution .

Comment: @MiaoLiu In your use case you've found the method that is fastest in raw speed, you've done the right thing. this is a more generic solution for a different problem

Comment: Yes, agree with @Suparshva For example this string will be assumed as correct date, without ValueError: "2018-10-1"

Answer (score 105):

The [Python `dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library is designed for this (and more). It will automatically convert this to a `datetime` object for you and raise a `ValueError` if it can't.

As an example:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("2003-09-25")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 0, 0)
```

This raises a `ValueError` if the date is not formatted correctly:

```
>>> parse("2003-09-251")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jacinda/envs/dod-backend-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 720, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jacinda/envs/dod-backend-dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 317, in parse
    ret = default.replace(**repl)
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

`dateutil` is also extremely useful if you start needing to parse other formats in the future, as it can handle most known formats intelligently and allows you to modify your specification: [`dateutil` parsing examples](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c).

It also handles timezones if you need that.

**Update based on comments**: `parse` also accepts the keyword argument `dayfirst` which controls whether the day or month is expected to come first if a date is ambiguous. This defaults to False. E.g.

```
>>> parse('11/12/2001')
>>> datetime.datetime(2001, 11, 12, 0, 0) # Nov 12
>>> parse('11/12/2001', dayfirst=True)
>>> datetime.datetime(2001, 12, 11, 0, 0) # Dec 11
```

Comment: it may accept too much e.g., `parse('13/12/2001')` is "13 Dec" but `parse('11/12/2001')` is "12 Nov" (the first result would suggest "11 Dec" here).

Comment: `parse` actually takes a `dayfirst` keyword argument that allows you to control this.  `parse('11/12/2001', dayfirst=True)` will return "11 Dec." dateutil's default is `dayfirst=False`

Comment: you are missing the point that `datetutil.parser.parse()` accepts too many time formats (you could find other examples with ambiguous input). If you want to *validate* that your input is in YYYY-MM-DD format then the `parse()` function is the wrong tool.

Comment: That's a completely valid point - if you really want to restrict to just that specific format this doesn't do that, and the accepted answer already does a great job of doing the right thing in that case.  I think when I wrote the answer I was thinking more along the lines of pointing out how to validate whether it was a valid date as opposed to the particular format that the author requested, which when people come across this question is what they're often looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to get `.parse()` to return the format string in addition to the `datetime` object?

Comment: I find this function problematic - parse('1') is valid. But, really, it is not.

Answer (score 73):

I think the full validate function should look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def validate(date_text):
    try:
        if date_text != datetime.strptime(date_text, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
            raise ValueError
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Executing just

```
datetime.strptime(date_text, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

is not enough because strptime method doesn't check that month and day of the month are zero-padded decimal numbers. For example

```
datetime.strptime("2016-5-3", '%Y-%m-%d')
```

will be executed without errors.

Comment: "You are technically correct - the best kind of correct." I needed to ensure this in my strings.

Comment: This works fine against my tests, however I the documentation seems incorrect as it states: "%d -> Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number -> 01, 02, …, 31"  and the same for the %m -> Month as a zero-padded decimal number. -> 01, 02, …, 12
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: If you need to check that month and day are zero-padded, wouldn't it suffice just to check the length of the string and `datetime.strptime(date_text, "%Y-%m-%d")`?

Comment: this is the only correct answer. especially when there are multiple datetime formats that need to be supported

Answer (score 23):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

..this raises a `ValueError` if it receives an incompatible format.

..if you're dealing with dates and times a lot (in the sense of datetime objects, as opposed to unix timestamp floats), it's a good idea to look into the pytz module, and for storage/db, store everything in UTC.

Comment: You were faster, I would have posted it myself (http://ideone.com/vuxDDf). Upvote.

Comment: ..just saw it right after it was posted, and happen to have been working with datetime objects today.

Answer (score 5):

From mere curiosity, I timed the two rivalling answers posted above.
And I had the following results:

```sh
dateutil.parser (valid str): 4.6732222699938575
dateutil.parser (invalid str): 1.7270505399937974
datetime.strptime (valid): 0.7822393209935399
datetime.strptime (invalid): 0.4394566189876059
```

And here's the code I used (Python 3.6)

```py
from dateutil import parser as date_parser
from datetime import datetime
from timeit import timeit


def is_date_parsing(date_str):
    try:
        return bool(date_parser.parse(date_str))
    except ValueError:
        return False


def is_date_matching(date_str):
    try:
        return bool(datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    except ValueError:
        return False



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("dateutil.parser (valid date):", end=' ')
    print(timeit("is_date_parsing('2021-01-26')",
                 setup="from __main__ import is_date_parsing",
                 number=100000))

    print("dateutil.parser (invalid date):", end=' ')
    print(timeit("is_date_parsing('meh')",
                 setup="from __main__ import is_date_parsing",
                 number=100000))

    print("datetime.strptime (valid date):", end=' ')
    print(timeit("is_date_matching('2021-01-26')",
                 setup="from __main__ import is_date_matching",
                 number=100000))

    print("datetime.strptime (invalid date):", end=' ')
    print(timeit("is_date_matching('meh')",
                 setup="from __main__ import is_date_matching",
                 number=100000))
```