# Django REST "GET" query params serializer

Tags: python, django

I want to receive get query and filter dataset with query params (if present). I'm currently using dumb method listed below. In this case I don't like the fact it's not checking that dates is actually could be parsed. In another method I may want to receive only numeric string which could be parsed to int. Is there some cool *pythonic* way to do it without writing a bunch of boilerplate code?

```
class TrackList(APIView):

    @token_required
    def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):
        # read query params
        date_from = self.request.query_params.get('date_from')
        date_to = self.request.query_params.get('date_to')
        # if present then filter
        if date_from and date_to:
            points = Track.objects.filter(user_id=pk, date__range=[date_from, date_to])
        # otherwise don't filter
        else:
            points = Track.objects.filter(user_id=pk)
        points.order_by('date')
        serializer = TrackListSerializer(points, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

UPD: The question is not actually about *dateutil.parser*, it is about general query params parser. Maybe I should use Django rest serializers?

Comment: You'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: check http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870663 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341945

Comment: Maybe you find django-filter useful: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think for above case we have to use the package `django-filter`.
To install it `pip install django-filter` and its better to use Generic Views.

1. add below code in `settings.py`

   ```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
      'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
    }
   ```
2. working with views & filters

   ```
    from rest_framework import generics
    from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
    from myapp import Track    

    class TrackFilter(filters.FilterSet):
        from_date = filters.DateFilter(field_name="date", lookup_expr='gte')
        to_date = filters.DateFilter(field_name="date", lookup_expr='lte')

        class Meta:
          model = Track
          fields = ['date']

    class TrackListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
      queryset = Track.objects.all()
      serializer_class = TrackListSerializer
      filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,) # optional
      filterset_class = TrackFilter
   ```

Usage:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/endpoint/?from_date=2018-01-01&to_date=2018-01-18
```

References:
http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filterset.html
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: nowadays, django-filter uses "field_name" instead of "name"
filters.DateFilter(*field_name*="date"....

Comment: Nowadays instead of filter_class, should be filterset_class.
And instead of name should be field_name.