# Issues checking valid date format in python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm new to python, and have little experience using try & except statements.
My code needs to check the date format entered by user. I'm currently using the code from this thread:

[How do I validate a date string format in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870663/how-do-i-validate-a-date-string-format-in-python)

but it's not working properly:
i.e. the following do not raise an exception, where date_text = "20189901", as does date_text = "20181301"

```
import datetime
date_text = "20189901"
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y%m%d')
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYYMMDD")
```

Is there a way to check date format using a simple if statement?

Comment: It is possible. But why would you use an `if` statement instead of `try` / `except`?

Comment: What do you mean? It raises the exception for me.

Comment: not sure if this is what you want but to avoid your problem you could just replace, `except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYYMMDD")` with `except:
 print("Incorrect data format, should be YYYYMMDD")`

Comment: date_text = "20189901" and "20181301" are both invalid dates. The code above doesn't recognise this, and treats them as valid.. except ValueError is not 'triggering'.I would prefer an if statement, but try / except is fine.. I just need it to work properly