# python - validating date with datetime

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I'm am trying to validate a `string` prompted for the user. This `string` should be write in the format `dd/mm/aaaa` and be a valid date. I thought than create a lot of `if` to check is not be ellegant, so i research and picked-up the `datetime` way.

```
import datetime

dataInput = input("Insira sua data de nascimento no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa': ")

ehDataValida = False

def validaData(dataInput) :
    while True :
            try :
                if dataInput != datetime.datetime.strptime(dataInput, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y") :
                    raise ValueError
                return False
            except ValueError:
                print("erro!")
                dataInput = input("Insira sua data de nascimento no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa': ")
                return dataInput

validaData(dataInput)
print(validaData(dataInput))
```

It's not working and for each test I found a new bug. What i'm missing? After this, I will `dataInput.split('/')` and achieve the date in a `listData=[dd, mm, yyyy]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870663/how-do-i-validate-a-date-string-format-in-python

Comment: i saw this topic and many others but i can't figure out a solution. what I'm tryng to implement was found in this topic, but i not reach the behavior yet: just `check`, and in case of `error`, `prompt` the user again and, so , if validated, `update` the `data_input var` ...

Comment: just remembered, reading ` / ` in  won't work.

Comment: try the modified answer @Lucas Maraal ..  your input is being read as integer, eg: if you input 12/2/1992, it is performing division operation as ((12 / 2) / 1992) which  results in zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is being read as integer, eg: if you input 12/2/1992, it is performing division operation as ((12 / 2) / 1992) which results in zero.  Use raw_input instead

```
import datetime

dataInput = raw_input("Insira sua data de nascimento no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa': ")

ehDataValida = False

def validaData(dataInput) :
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(dataInput, '%d/%m/%y')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Insira sua data de nascimento no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa': ")

validaData(dataInput)
```

Try this. It should work

```
while True:
    try:
        dataInput = raw_input("Insira sua data de nascimento no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa': ")
        date_formatted = datetime.datetime.strptime(dataInput, '%d/%m/%y')
        break
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Insira sua data de nascimento no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa': ")
```

Comment: could you be kind enough to translate 'Insira sua data de nascimento no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa': ' , I'm assuming it means wrong format , please try again, If you are trying to create an input prompt after exception error, No,, then my code is incomplete ,my code merely raises an error message.

Comment: Yeah, this works. Just a thing: i think in  Python do not have `raw_input`, but doing `dataInput = str(input("Insira sua data de nascimento no formato 'dd/mm/aaaa': "))`

Works. Thank you.

(the translate is: Insert you bithday's date in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy')

if you want to see: https://ideone.com/XfU92V

Comment: @LucasMaraal look at the edits, it should loop until it is successfull,

Comment: i marked, but i tried this last edit solution and not woks... the another one works.

Comment: let me check once more,