# Is there a way to make an error message for an incorrect value in a field?

Tags: python, date, contract

I am writing a python code to generate a contract when particular fields are filled
the date field accepts any data instead of dd/mm/yyyy. I want an error message to be generated when an incorrect value is entered and until the right format is entered, the user cannot jump to the next field.

`````
print("Hello, Welcome to Rent contract generator!")
def get():
    first = input("Enter your name: ")
    last = input("Enter your last name: ")
    bday = input("Enter your birthday (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
    address = input("Enter your address: ")
    userid = input("Enter your ID number: ")

    inputdata = (first, last, bday, address, userid)
    print("Hello " + first + "! " + "Your rental contract is ready now :)")
    
    return inputdata````
`````

Comment: the term `field` is not clear. can you show your code?

Comment: # 1. get user input
print("Hello, Welcome to Rent contract generator!")
def get():
    first = input("Enter your name: ")
    last = input("Enter your last name: ")
    bday = input("Enter your birthday (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
    address = input("Enter your address: ")
    userid = input("Enter your ID number: ")

Comment: To validate a date format, please have a look at already given answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870663/how-do-i-validate-a-date-string-format-in-python