# How can I use regex in python to validate dates in the MM/DD/YYYY format?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project for my beginning python class and it's heavily focused on regex. Part of this project involves using regex to validate the date format MM/DD/YYYY.

My Regex is as follows:

```
(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:0?[1-9]|12\d|3[01])\/(?:1\d{3})
```

I'm having an issue where if I enter a date like

```
13/31/1999
```

my regex wont match the first 1, but instead will match

```
3/31/1999
```

I'm not sure why this is happening because I'm expecting if the DD starts with a 1, then my regex should only match that 1 followed by either 0,1,2.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/pjavjp/1) is a visual representation of my issue

Comment: You may want to match the start (`^`) and maybe the end (`$`) of your string. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just needed to add the caret symbol to the start and that fixed my problem.

Comment: You may find this of use if you're not forced to use regex: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16870663/2449857

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For the record, this was solved in the comments) Add the caret (`^`) at the beginning of your regular expression to match the beginning of the string. That should match your requirement:

```
^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:0?[1-9]|12\d|3[01])\/(?:1\d{3})
```

You can see it working with your examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/GJxc2W/1).