# parsing date using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have following text

```
txt = 'Lithium 0.25 (7/11/77).  LFTS wnl.  Urine tox neg.  Serum tox + fluoxetine 500; otherwise neg.  TSH 3.28.  BUN/Cr: 16/0.83.  Lipids unremarkable.  B12 363, Folate >20.  CBC: 4.9/36/308 Pertinent Medical Review of Systems Constitutional:'
```

I want to get date in above expression and i have written following expression.

```
re.findall(r'(?:[\d{1,2}]+)(?:[/-]\d{0,}[/-]\d{2,4})', txt)
```

If I execute above expression following output is shown

['7/11/77', '9/36/308']

I don't want "4.9/36/308" this to be included how do I have to change regular expression for this.

Kindly help.

Comment: I don't know about you but `7/11/77` isn't a date either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579725/return-string-with-first-match-regex ?

Comment: 7/11/77 I consider as a date because according to my requirement if last number is two digits append 19 before it to make a year. Thanks I forgot to mentioned in question

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Maybe I missed something, but why not?

Answer (score 1):

You may fix the current regex as

```
\b(?<!\.)\d{1,2}[/-]\d+[/-]\d{2,4}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RRp2oW/2)

The `\b` will match a word boundary and `(?<!\.)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if there is a `.` before the first digit matched.

See the [Python demo](http://import%20re%20rx%20=%20r%22%5Cb(?%3C!%5C.)%5Cd%7B1,2%7D[/-]%5Cd%20[/-]%5Cd%7B2,4%7D%5Cb%22%20s%20=%20%22Lithium%200.25%20(7/11/77).%20%20LFTS%20wnl.%20%20Urine%20tox%20neg.%20%20Serum%20tox%20%20%20fluoxetine%20500;%20otherwise%20neg.%20%20TSH%203.28.%20%20BUN/Cr:%2016/0.83.%20%20Lipids%20unremarkable.%20%20B12%20363,%20Folate%20%3E20.%20%20CBC:%204.9/36/308%20Pertinent%20Medical%20Review%20of%20Systems%20Constitutional:%22%20print(re.findall(rx,%20s))).

Note that you will have to use a [non-regex method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987818/in-python-how-to-check-if-a-date-is-valid) later if you need to only get a list of *valid* dates.